# Parse doesn't return PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a pointer to an object in my [PFUser currentUser] and when I'm trying to access values inside that object I get `internal ObjC exception breakpoint`.

this is my code:

```
PFObject *object = [PFUser currentUser][@"localityData"];
NSString *value = [object objectForKey:@"language"];
```

I get the error on the second line.

Also, Unless I do

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) { ...
```

every time I ask for

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectWithKey:@"SOMEKEY"]
```

I get `nil` in return, why is this happening?

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: @Wain actually, this isn't an exception, its when I try to `po` in the debugger, If I actually write the code like I showed in the example and using a breakpoint step into it just never moves to the next line.

Comment: What do you `po`? The `object`?

Comment: @Wain this is my po `po [[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"localityData"] objectForKey:@"countryCode"]`  and I get this error in the debugger: `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

Comment: So break it down and `po` each part to find the area of the issue. Have you called `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock` before doing this?

Comment: @Wain I did break it down, when I po `[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"localityData"] ` I get `<LocalityData: 0x17013de20, objectId: o4V2f1towy, localId: (null)> {
}` However when I try to access any of its properties I get the exception, I did `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock` before calling the `po`

Comment: Did you setup local data source for you application https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore/iOS ? It seems it does not save User's reloations on the device. What exception did you get? Please add it to the original post

Comment: @MaxK this is without local data stores, I am not using them, just trying to get the object from [`PFUser currentUser]`

Comment: Call `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock` on the `LocalityData` object you get back (though you shouldn't get an exception if that's the missing part...)

Comment: @Wain using `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock` does work, but it is really wired since according to the documentation I should do a fetch every time I need an object.. I think this is  a bug

Comment: IIRC there is a 'fetch if needed in background' method - and by working you mean prevents the exception / hang?

Comment: @Wain Yes,  and I also get the data, but I think It's a really strange behaviour that I need to check if I need to fetch instead of it fetching automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse doesn't fetch for you automatically, except a few pieces of data in specific scenarios. Like, when a user logs in the current user will be fetched and will include the standard user data - but it won't include any custom data.

If you fetch an object then that objects details will be downloaded, but the details of related objects won't - unless you specifically request it to be included in the query that you make (using `includeKey:`).

It's generally best to always use `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:` if you aren't sure whether the data you need has been obtained yet. Not doing this shouldn't cause a crash but it will generally cause you issues with missing information. It's possible that the crash is related to parse using exceptions for navigation in the framework, but that's a guess and you might want to try contacting parse to see if you can get more details.